# Could not find H:\Android\tools\adb.exe

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When I configure Eclipse to point to my SDK, it show "Could not find H:\Android\tools\adb.exe".
Actually, I know the file is in the platform-tools folder not in the tools folder. The eclipse I used is 3.5.2 and the Android SDK i used is r16. How to solve the issue? Who can help me?

Comment: Double check in the SDK manager if you have the platform-tools installed, or try to reinstall them.

Comment: What Eclipse ADT plugin version you are using?

Comment: please add an edit on how you solved the issue

Comment: Ok.My issue is the eclipse can't find the adb.exe in tools folder.Actually,the file is in platform-tools folder.After google.I know,In the older SDK, the files in tools and Platform-tools folder all is in the tools folder.So i change the name of tools folder and put all the files of the old tools and Platform-tools folder into the new tools folder i creat.So i configure Eclipse to point to my SDK successful.

Comment: But when i creat new AVD,there are only have Android 1.6.In fact,i dowload the API from andrion 1.6 to android 4.0.After check the platforms folder.I find in addition to android-4,there are no the folder of ant,samples and tools.I copy those folders to others.Thus,all the issues was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Normally adb.exe remain in **\eclipse\eclipse\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools**chack yout SDK path

Answer (score 0):

update your Eclipse and then try again